# What is the equivalent log4j statement in scala for the below java code

Tags: scala

I am trying to use log4j in scala . I have log4j file properly placed inside resources directory as well.

I am following the same log4j approach which has been followed in java

**My Java Code  : This Works fine. No issues at all**

```
package pack1;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SampleMain {
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleMain.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampleMain lld = new SampleMain();
    lld.log();
}


public void log() {
    logger.fatal("This is fatal.");
    logger.error("This is error.");
    logger.warn("This is warn.");
    logger.info("This is info.");
    logger.debug("This is debug.");
    logger.trace("This is trace.");
  }


}
```

**My Scala Code :**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


class SampleScala {

   val logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleScala.class)//getting compile time error at this line .  

  def method1():Unit = {

  }

}
object ScalaLogging {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val obj = new SampleScala();
obj.method1()

 }
}
```

**Compile time Error in above scala Code :**

```
 identifier expected but 'class' found.
```

So I would like to know what is the equivalent scala statement for the below java code

```
  final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleMain.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is

```
val logger = Logger getLogger classOf[SampleMain]
```